# Separate table row to 2 when scraping with pandas read_html

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

Can't get the *row* format correct when using pandas `read_html()`. I'm looking for adjustments either to the method itself or the underlying html (scraped via bs4) to get the desired output.

Current output:

[image: Current wrong output format]
*(note it is 1 row containing two types of data. ideally it should be separated to 2 rows as below)*

Desired:

[image: Desired output format]

**code to replicate the issue:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # alternatively

url = "http://ufcstats.com/fight-details/bb15c0a2911043bd"

df = pd.read_html(url)[-1]  # last table
df.columns = [str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]

# to get the html via bs4
headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
}
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
table_html = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "b-fight-details__table"})[-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How to (quick) fix with `beautifulsoup`

You can create a `dict` with the headers from the `table` and then iterate over each `td` to append the list of values stored in the `p`:

```
data = {}

header = [x.text.strip() for x in table_html.select('tr th')]

for i,td in enumerate(table_html.select('tr:has(td) td')):
    data[header[i]] = [x.text.strip() for x in td.select('p')]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

#### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # alternatively

url = "http://ufcstats.com/fight-details/bb15c0a2911043bd"

# to get the html via bs4
headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
}
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
table_html = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "b-fight-details__table"})[-1]

data = {}

header = [x.text.strip() for x in table_html.select('tr th')]

for i,td in enumerate(table_html.select('tr:has(td) td')):
    data[header[i]] = [x.text.strip() for x in td.select('p')]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

#### Output

| Fighter | Sig. str | Sig. str. % | Head | Body | Leg | Distance | Clinch | Ground |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joanne Wood | 27 of 68 | 39% | 8 of 36 | 3 of 7 | 16 of 25 | 26 of 67 | 1 of 1 | 0 of 0 |
| Taila Santos | 30 of 60 | 50% | 21 of 46 | 3 of 7 | 6 of 7 | 19 of 42 | 0 of 0 | 11 of 18 |

Comment: great solution, thanks! I had to adjust it a bit to get the right format on tables with more than 1 row. for instance, your code breaks when url="http://ufcstats.com/fight-details/18f19b1422e8154b".

adjustments i made:
```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

header = [x.text.strip() for x in table_html.select('tr th')]

i =0
for td in table_html.select('tr:has(td) td'):
    data[header[i]].extend([x.text.strip() for x in td.select('p')])
    i+=1
    if i==len(header):
        i=0

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to use enumerate to determine number of rows, but use `:-soup-contains` to target table, then `nth-child` selector to extract relevant row during list comprehension. `pandas` to convert resultant list of lists into a DataFrame. Assumes rows are added in same pattern as current 2.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://ufcstats.com/fight-details/bb15c0a2911043bd')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one(
    '.js-fight-section:has(p:-soup-contains("Significant Strikes")) + table')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[i.text.strip() for i in table.select(f'tr:nth-child(1) td p:nth-child({n+1})')]
     for n, _ in enumerate(table.select('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > p'))], columns=[i.text.strip() for i in table.select('th')])

print(df)
```